# React Router working locally but not deployed on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have ran my app on localhost and everything works fine, however once I deploy on heroku the home page works correctly, but when I hit "my-app/stocks/AAPL" I get a 404. I have looked at others with the issue and added a static.json file, but that does not help. I have pasted my code from my server.js, my folder structure, static.json, and my App.js for reference.

static.json

```
{
    "root": "client/build/",
    "clean_urls": false,
    "routes": {
      "/**": "index.html"
    }
  }
```

server.js

```
const stockRouter = require('./routes/stock')
const userRouter = require('./routes/user')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config()
const app = express()


app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true});
const connection = mongoose.connection

connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log('MongoDB connection successful')
});

app.use('/stock', stockRouter)
app.use('/user', userRouter)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

// for local env, use /client/public folder
else {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/public')));
}

// server the client index.html file for all requests
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/public/index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, (req, res) => {
    console.log('Listening')
})
```

app.js

```
function App() {
  return (

    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div className="App">
    <Container maxWidth='lg'>
      <Paper style={{ backgroundColor: '#f5f6f7'}}>
      <Nav></Nav>
      <Route exact path='/' component={StockTabs} />
      <Route exact path='/stocks/:symbol' component={StockInfo} />
      </Paper>
      </Container>
    </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  
  );
}
```

file structure
[image: File Structure]

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the URL: `my-app/stocks/AAPL`, the default behavior of browser is sent a request to your server and you do not have the handler for that route on your server so 404 returns.

You have 2 ways to handle that case:

1. Use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`, your URL should look like:

   `YOUR_SERVER:PORT/#/stocks/AAPL`

The # on the URL does not trigger server call and routing will be handled by client entirely.

2. You still can use `BrowserRouter` but it need to configure on your server, read on that post for more information: [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)